# OnBoarding After successful signin with nextauth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

How can I redirect users to the onboarding page on first signin in Next.js with NextAuth?

Here is my `/auth/[...next]/route.js`:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import next from "next";
//const handler = NextAuth({});
const prisma = new PrismaClient();
export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      return user;
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      return baseUrl;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
      // if (isNewUser) token.isNewUser = isNewUser;
      if (isNewUser) {
        // Redirect new users to onboarding
        redirect("/onboarding");
      } else {
        // Continue with the request
        next();
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

As you can see I tried redirecting inside the jwt callback but I get the error:

> https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_handler_error NEXT_REDIRECT {
> message: 'NEXT_REDIRECT',

Here is my `middleware.js`:

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/"],
};
```

I am using NextAuth `v4` and Next.js `v13.3.4`.

Comment: `NEXTAUTH_URL  = http://localhost:3001` add this to your .env file. Change port to your localhost running port.

Comment: Thank you for the response but I already have it configured including the NEXT_AUTH_SECRET and other necessary .env variables

Comment: Can you share your env.

Comment: Ok here it is:


DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:root@localhost:5432/proserve?schema=public"
SHADOW_DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:root@localhost:5432/shadowdb?schema=public"

NEXTAUTH_SECRET = ZSE4XDR5CFT6
NEXTAUTH_URL = http://localhost:3000


I have excluded the Google variables

Comment: Are you getting user token and all after signin.

Comment: Okay you mean change it to  http://localhost:3001?

Yes I am so all I need is to then redirect the user to the onboarding page.

Comment: Have you created pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js file.

Comment: yes that's the code at the top according to the current version of nextauth and nextjs 13

Comment: WOuld you like to join on meet. To join the video meeting, click this link: https://meet.google.com/yet-eivq-toj
Otherwise, to join by phone, dial +1 401-830-3181 and enter this PIN: 811 686 656#

Comment: ok let me set it up

Comment: Can you share where you called signin method

Comment: This is from the signin page

<Button
          onClick={() => signIn("google", { redirect: true })}
          variant="outline"
          className="w-full mt-6"
        >

Comment: try this once. ` const result = await signIn("google", {
      redirect: true,
      callbackUrl: "/",
    });`

Comment: still getting this error:

https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_handler_error NEXT_REDIRECT {
  message: 'NEXT_REDIRECT',
  stack: 'Error: NEXT_REDIRECT\n' +

Comment: please join on above link.

Comment: I am not able to push to your repo.

Comment: I tried multiple solution on your code. What worked for me is moving your api folder to pages folder, adding a secret in the nextauth.js , adding a error file in api/auth/error.tsx

Comment: Okay umm what error are you getting when you try to push?

Comment: not authorized.